# colorbox dealing with validation and auto height issue

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I am using colorbox plugin for showing popups and modals in my application, Its a very good plugin. One problem is that height is not automatically adjusted in popup how can I deal with it?

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate a form shown in popup, but as soon as form shows validation errors the colorbox shows a scrollbar. I want to auto adjust its height.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the API for ColorBox, it explains that you can call `resize()`.

Quoted from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox:

> `$.colorbox.resize()`
>
> This allows ColorBox to be resized based on it's own auto-calculations, or to a specific size. This must be called manually after ColorBox's content has loaded. The optional parameters object can accept `width` or `innerWidth` and `height` or `innerHeight`. Without specifying a width or height, ColorBox will attempt to recalculate the height of it's current content.

So when you do your validations, just call `$.colorbox.resize()` to tell the ColorBox to resize itself.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/zX6SX/) so you can see it in action.

Comment: what to do when validate plugin is dynamically showing error on edit of input boxes? I need to resize onvalidate event?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer your questions if you could post your code. Whenever you need the box to resize, call `$.colorbox.resize()` and it will adjust its own height. In your case when validation errors appear.